# How do i get my cat to stop climbing my blinds to get on my bed

Tags: cats, behavior, sleep, bedding

My cat constantly climbs my windows to get up onto my bed (I have a loft) the problem is:

1. My fans very close to the bed and she always hits her tail when she up there
2. She can't get down by herself and
3. I'm allergic to cats and my bed is my safe space away from everyone where I get to relax at but I can't relax when I'm sneezing every 5 seconds.

I've tried blocking my windows with things like cardboard and pillows so she can't climb up but she always finds a way. I've tried deterrant spray as well.

She's blind so for her to keep doing this is really not healthy. She has plenty of toys, time with me when I'm not on my bed( I'm rarely on it) a huge cat tree, feline companions, plenty of food, and plenty of beds.

I'm getting desperate y'all. I love her to death but I cannot get any good sleep and it's affecting both my mental and physical health. I've never rewarded her for getting on my bed in fact I always take her off my bed if I'm not sleeping when she sneaks on. Please help I've tried everything. I can't lock her out of my room at night as I have dogs and other cats that might hurt her and she can't defend herself.

Comment: That may be a strange question (and please don’t feel offended), but if you are allergic to cats, why do you keep one in your room and more in your household? Allergies have a tendency to worsen if not managed and allergic asthma or anaphylactic shock is no picknick, trust me on that.

Comment: @Stephie while it depends on the individual nature of the allergy, it sounds like in this case, either it's severe enough that keeping cats isn't a good idea, or it's a psychosomatic response to the idea of an allergy. I've tested as allergic to cats, and do get congested around unfamiliar ones, but also habituate to familiar ones and have three I'm adjusted to.

Comment: @AllisonC same with my godchild. He would love a cat, mommy would agree in a heartbeat, but he starts wheezing in most cases when they visit family with cats. But he’s fine with a few individual specimens, e.g. our Chester.

Answer (score 1):

Option one:  Make it impossible for the cat to continue. You can do this by either replacing the blinds with something that's impossible for it to climb, such as window film, vertical blinds rather than horizontal blinds, or maybe a free standing folding screen, or simply by keeping the cat in its own room at night, so that it won't bother you, and it won't be bothered by your other animals.

Option two:  You can continue down the route you're currently taking, but step it up by not only using deterrents, but also adding in desirable alternatives. The cat keeps doing this because it wants to be near you, so give it a space to sleep that is near you, and will hopefully seem better to the cat than your bed. I'm thinking a cat bed right next to your bed that's easy for the cat to get into, perhaps with a heating pad, and has one of your used items of clothes in it, so it also smells like you. Since your bed is a loft, it also might make sense to use cat furniture to elevate the bed, to make the cat as close to you as possible. Just make sure that the cat can't climb from its bed to your bed.

Obviously this method is by no means guaranteed to work, but if you can get it to work, it's a more harmonious option than just shutting the cat out. You could also try combining this option with the idea of replacing the blinds with something the cat can't climb.